# Как запретить мобильному броузеру переходить к предыдущей-следующей странице при свайпе?

Tags: javascript

Реализовано простое листание фотографий влево-вправо пальцем на сенсорном экране. Каждая фотка в отдельном html'е, при нажатии/отпускании на достаточном расстоянии влево-вправо грузится предыдущий-следующий файл.

```
var touch_position; // Координата нажатия 
function turn_start(event) { 
    // При начальном нажатии получить координаты 
    touch_position = event.touches[0].pageX; 
    document.getElementById("nameid").innerHTML = "" + touch_position;
} 
function turn_page(event) { 
    // При движении нажатия отслеживать направление движения 
    var tmp_move = touch_position-event.touches[0].pageX; 
    // Сдвиг достаточный? 
    if (Math.abs(tmp_move) < 50) { return false; } 
    if (tmp_move < 0) { 
        document.location.href = "16.htm";
    } 
    else { 
        document.location.href = "02.htm";
    } 
}
```

Но эта реализация работает не очень, иногда при слишком длинном проведении пальцем вместе с перелистыванием броузер переходит к предыдущей-следующей странице (и в итоге все остается на той же). Можно ли как-то это перехватить?